# static css and js files versioning

Tags: angularjs, static-files

I have an angular app and I'm facing the situation of taking care of the versioning of my static CSS and JS files?

right now my browsers won’t update the files except with hard-refresh, the old solution for this is to add a version number to each file to do cache busting.

I have been checking the tools on the web, Is using gulp or grunt is going to solve this when the code is deployed to production? I have also read about SaaS for my css file but what I understand is that it is used for minifying my files, does it solve this matter for css files? and how about my js files?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your backend (Node? Django?) you should be able to specify the cache timeout the browsers should respect.

Here's an example with Node:

```
var oneHour = 3600 * 1000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {maxAge: oneHour}));
```

Comment: but if I change a file and upload to prod, and I want to see the change immediately regardless of the cache timeout @muli-yulzary

Comment: Have a look at the cache specification https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3